# Dotenv file in custom plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want to create some hidden settings that only a developer can change. For this purpose, I would like to have a .env file in my wordpress plugin. How do I read the settings from .env file in my plugin classes.

Is there any other way I can have hidden settings in my plugin?

Thanks

Comment: WordPress doesn’t have methods for reading a .env file, so this is more of a PHP question. But a .env file is still going to be overwritten by plugin updates. So if you want developers to be able to change the settings you’d need to let them place their own file in the root, uploads, or child theme directory. But normally for this sort of thing you just support a filter. How many settings are we talking about here?

Comment: normally this would be done via filters or `wp-config.php` constants, otherwise when your plugin gets updated the folder is removed and replaced, along with the .env file. Also this file might be considered a security thread by some security software, and it will be available to the open web on some systems

Comment: @JacobPeattie We are talking about 2 or 3 settings. How can I do it with filters?